# Django custom template tags imitating {% block %} behavior

Tags: django, django-templates

I was studying [Django custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) and got a question about the possibilities of custom tags.

Assume I have a construction like

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block leftmenu %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div id="#leftmenu">
            ...
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

and I want to shorten it like

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load myawesometags %}
{% myblock leftmenu %}
    ...
{% endmyblock %}
```

I can't just create custom tag adding `<div>` and removing spaces cause without `{% block ... %}` the content won't take it's place in the base template. So, the question is: is it possible to emulate standard Django blocks in custom template tags?

Comment: It is possible, though I think this kind of template tag is not expected to be customized. The easiest way is probably to (somewhat) copy the `do_block` function https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/loader_tags.py#L172 to use your `BlockNode` and inherit the `BlockNode` class to do what you want.

Comment: It seems you're right! I would accept this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, though I think this kind of template tag is not expected to be customized.

The easiest way is probably to inherit the `BlockNode` class to do what you want and (somewhat) copy the `do_block()` function https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/loader_tags.py#L172 to use your `BlockNode`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write a block tag, however you should know that block tag and extends tag work together. If you look at the code for [`BlockNode`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/loader_tags.py#L41) and [`ExtendsNode`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/loader_tags.py#L75) you will see how they render the template contents together.

ExtendNode captures all the block nodes from current template and the parent template. These blocks are stored in render_context with key BLOCK_CONTEXT_KEY and with value as instance of BlockContext. All the blocks are added to BlockContext using method add_blocks which uses FIFO (first-in-first-out) queue. Once all the block nodes are stored ExtendNode then renders the parent template. This causes the BlockNode instances to be rendered in the parent template. BlockNode then picks the BlockContext from render_context to get the block data. And because of FIFO, when BlockNode pops the block object from BlockContext it picks the last block, i.e. the one it encounters last in the inheritance. That's what I understood when reading the code. If I missed something please correct me.

You may be able to inherit BlockNode to customize it to a certain degree.